# Split string using substring

Tags: java, android, adt

I am new to android and i have a following scenario below.

I have the following string below

```
file=android.txt&data="sampleExample"
```

How can I extract the substrings **android.txt** and **sampleExample**?

NOTE: I tried the following code

```
myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf('=')+1, myString.length() );
```

but it returns output as **SampleExample**.

Please help me on this issue

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to me `substring`?

Comment: What have you tried? Check out [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) for useful functions in the String class.

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: are you saying you want to take as input "file=android.txt&data=it contains android data" and then with a call to string.split have just "android.txt" and "it contains android data" ??

Comment: Your second comment negates first one. I asked if you have to use `substring` and you said yes (at least I assume that it was answer for my comment), but then Mugambo asks you if you "*with a call to string.`split`*" and you are saying yes... So which is it, do you have to use `substring` or are you allowed to use other methods like `split`?

Comment: you also said you DO want to get "it contains android data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `split` method from `String` class.

Split `file=android.txt&data=it contains android data`

on `&` to get array of `"file=android.txt"` and `"data=it contains android data"`.

Then you can split each of this elements on `=` so

`file=android.txt` -> `file`, `android.txt`
`data=it contains android data` -> `data`, `it contains android data`

So your code can look like

```
foreach element in data.split(&)
   array = element.split(=)
   get second element from array
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
String myString = "file=android.txt&data=it contains android data";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^file=([^&]+)&data=(.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String first = matcher.group(1);
    String second = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
String body = "file=android.txt&data=it contains android data"
String[] data = body.substring(body.indexOf('=')+1, body.length()).split("&data=");

// data[0] = "android.txt"
// data[1] = "it contains android data"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your input string looks like a query string. I. e. a list of key/value pairs that are seperated by '&'.

I would split each key/value pair into a String and then extract the value after the first '='.

```
    String input = "file=android.txt&data=it contains android data"; 
    String[] items = input.split("&"); 
    String[] results = new String[items.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        int pos = item.indexOf("=");
        if (pos == -1)
            results[i] = null; 
        else
            results[i] = items[i].substring(pos + 1); 
    }

    // results now holds your strings.
```